# Trying to count different document types for a project within a given time range

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to create a report and count documents / projects within a given time range. I think I am doing something wrong with the where clause.

What I have:

- A project table with project ids
- Different document tables each with an document id, project id, and a document creation date:

projecttable

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

document type A table

| id | projectId | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-02-12T05:24:22.420 |
| 2 | 3 | 2022-04-12T05:24:22.420 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022-03-12T05:24:22.420 |
| 4 | 3 | 2022-02-12T05:24:22.420 |

document type B table

| id | projectId | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2022-01-12T05:24:22.420 |
| 2 | 3 | 2022-01-12T05:24:22.420 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022-05-12T05:24:22.420 |

Expected result:

**Given Time Range from 2022-01 to 2022-03**

| project id | count document a | count document b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |

I tried the following select:

```
    SELECT "project"."id",
       COUNT(DISTINCT(documenta.id)) AS documentA_total
       COUNT(DISTINCT(documentb.id)) AS documentB_total,       
FROM project
LEFT JOIN documenta ON documenta.projectid = project.id
LEFT JOIN documentb ON documentb.projectid = project.id
WHERE 
("documenta"."createdAt" BETWEEN '{{daterange.start}}' AND '{{daterange.end}}')
OR 
("documentb"."createdAt" BETWEEN '{{daterange.start}}' AND '{{daterange.end}}')
GROUP BY project.id;
```

I think the problem is at the where clause. Because I am getting the wrong countings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your join condition to include the date filter and remove them from where clause. I have renamed the table and column names for simplicity.  [Here is sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91189c/9)

```
 SELECT p.id,
   COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id)) AS documentA_total,
   COUNT(DISTINCT(b.id)) AS documentB_total      
FROM project p
LEFT JOIN docA a ON p.id = a.project_id and a.created_at BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-03-31'
LEFT JOIN docB b ON p.id = b.project_id and b.created_at BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-03-31'
GROUP BY p.id;
```

I have renamed the table and column names for simplicity. Your exact query will be similar to below query,

```
SELECT "project"."id",
       COUNT(DISTINCT(documenta.id)) AS documentA_total
       COUNT(DISTINCT(documentb.id)) AS documentB_total,       
FROM project
LEFT JOIN documenta ON documenta.projectid = project.id and "documenta"."createdAt" BETWEEN '{{daterange.start}}' AND '{{daterange.end}}'
LEFT JOIN documentb ON documentb.projectid = project.id and "documentb"."createdAt" BETWEEN '{{daterange.start}}' AND '{{daterange.end}}'
GROUP BY project.id;
```

Comment: Thanks a million. So the point was it to filter with the join. Now its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is no mysql code as it would not allow a column name with double quotes

But still, you must count the data before joining

```
SELECT "project"."id",
       COALESCE(documentA_total,0) AS documentA_total,
       COALESCE(documentB_total,0) AS documentB_total
FROM project
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(*) as documentA_total, projectid FROM documenta WHERE 
("documenta"."createdAt" BETWEEN '{{daterange.start}}' AND '{{daterange.end}}') GROUP BY projectid) as doca ON doca.projectid = project.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(*) as documentB_total, projectid FROM documentb WHERE ("documentb"."createdAt" BETWEEN '{{daterange.start}}' AND '{{daterange.end}}')
GROUP BY projectid) as docb ON docb.projectid = project.id
```